# Google Apps Script - Integrating XFrameOptions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, x-frame-options

I have built a Google App that I am using to feed real time data onto our website. The only problem I am having is integrating the  setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL); with my current code so that I can iFrame my Google App onto the website. Below is my current code:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function include(file) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(file).getContent();
}

function logNamesAndMajors() {
  var spreadsheetId = '1slxKpwZQybc7MZFOzpJcndtACqNrpEeBgGXSkbHLJ-U';
  var rangeName = 'Company Dashboard!A2:B';
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, 
  rangeName).values;

  return values;

  if (!values) {
    Logger.log('No data found.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('Name, Score:');
    for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
      // Print columns A and B, which correspond to indices 0 and 1.
      Logger.log(' - %s, %s', values[row][0], values[row][1]);
    }
  }
}
```

I had implemented the following code to the first part that setup the iFrame, but then my code wouldn't "get" any of the actual data, so I seem to be confused on how to build out the XFrameOptions to my specific code.

```
var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
  output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

Any help on where and how I need to integrate the XFrameOptions into my code so I can iFrame it in would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have solved it. I updated the function doGet() to read as follows: 
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
          .evaluate()
      
 .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it. I updated the function doGet() to read as follows:

```
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
    .evaluate()
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```